# NPM module or JS code to validate Firebase UIDs

Tags: node.js, firebase, npm, firebase-authentication

I am looking for some code that can generate amd validate a Firebase UID string as having the correct format

https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebase

Does anyone know if that exists? Can't find anything on NPM.

Comment: See how the Firebase UIDs are generated, it might help you: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/02/the-2120-ways-to-ensure-unique_68.html

Comment: @Rexford: Those are not UIDs, they're called push IDs. Trying to parse them is discouraged. Alex: What are you trying to accomplish? Can you give an example of the type of ID you're trying to validate?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen we are just doing some DB validation, and want to make sure certain fields have a string that is in fact a true UID, that is all. Does that make sense?

Comment: It's just a string of random characters. I'm not even sure it has a guaranteed length.

Comment: so any UUID library should work fine?